# operands " ` " and " $" with strings, for example toDateString

Tags: javascript, string

In this string

```
${string.toDateString()} - ${string2.toDateString()}
```

what do **$** and **`** mean?

Answer (score 0):

These are called **Template Literals** in Javascript.

A Template Literal is enclosed in back-ticks instead of single quotes or double quotes. The `${}` notation allows you to embed the string value of an enclosed variable or expression.

Read additional information about Javascript Template Literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals